# Ember Data: (best practice) Dynamic Parameter for find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

maybe it's just a brain bug on my side, but im really confused for many days now.

I have a search formula with many configurable changing parameters like this:

ID, name, lastname, date1,

There is no hierarchical order of these parameters, the user can configure them in and out of the form.

The ember way for queryparameter is : { ID: ..., lastname: ..., date1: ... }, but what can i do, if i don't know what parameters can face up? There are for different modules in our application from 10 to 40 Parameters configurable....

I need help to find the "best-practice" to solve this problem.
I would be delighted, if someone could give me an impact how to solve this!

Best regards, Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to find a reusable solution to not make a huge list of `if`s for different query params for `@store.find`.

To make it reusable, you can stay with single find as follows:

```
this.store.find('myModel', queryHash)
```

And build the `queryHash` before the call. You can for example have a set of checkboxes and a computed property that is based on all the checkboxes values. This computed property will build your hash, e.g.:

```
queryHash: Ember.computed "lastName", "date1", function() {
   query = {}
   if(this.get("lastName")) { query.lastName = this.get("lastName"); }
   if(this.get("date1")) { query.date1 = this.get("date1"); }
   query
});
```

The disadvantage is that you need to know all the possible options that are available (but does not need to be checked) in current route for the user (e.g. via some kind of inputs or form).

On the other hand, if you cannot say what are names (or how many of them there are), you can at least hold all user-provided data in some kind of an array and enumarate through it, adding all the proper hash keys with values to the `query` object.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way which i have chosen, but theres some problems with ember data with it.  I have nested json response and a custom serializer. in this configuration i end up with two store objects.. but this problem is hard to explain.  One Object has the id: 1  and the other has the value of the queryparams variable >>  id: ?identnummer=CL00000001&var2=x  so on,... hard to reproduce in jsbin or fiddle...

Comment: Hard to say what can cause the problem. I assume that the reason lies somewhere in your custom serializer. You can ask another question, including your serializer, model and adapter code + exact response from server, to let others mock it properly.